# Filebeat to Kafka - send or validate as Avro message?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, filebeat

I have Filebeat which outputs to Kafka topic and would like to make sure that messages are in correct format by using Avro schema.
In Filebeat documentation, there are mentioned two possible output codecs, `JSON` or `format`.
In Kafka, Schema registry can be used to store Avro schemas.

**My questions:**
Is is possible for Filebeat to send Avro message (validated against Avro schema); and if so, can schema be linked from Schema registry so it won't need to be physically copied over on each new version of schema ?
Can Filebeat's `JSON` or `format` message be considered as Avro by Kafka ?
If Filebeat can't produce validated Avro message, can JSON send be validated at Kafka's side, when trying to write to topic ? If so, can non-valid messages be dropped or logged somewhere ?

Comment: You can send the Filebeat output to Logstash which can then use the Apache Avro codec plugin to serialize the data and send it to the Kafka topic. This link shows how Filebeat communicates with Logstash, with backpressure handling: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat . And this URL has details on the Logstash Apache Avro codec plugin to serialize and de-serialize data as per the Apache Avro format: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-avro.html

Comment: Yeah, its not real solution what I was looking for, but this is probably the most close one in terms of length of pipeline. Thanks and marked as solution.